# Does the wait method immediately relinquish control of Lock

Tags: java, multithreading

I was reading the Java docs and it says about notify method that it will not immediately relinquish the control. That is if there is some code remain in the synchronized block of code after call to notify method then it will first complete the remaining code and then relinquish the control.

```
synchronized(this) {
// line 1
notify();
//line 2
// line 3
}
```

line 2 and line 3 will still be executed. Does the same functionality will go for the wait method that is

```
synchronized(this) {
// line 1
wait();
//line 2
// line 3
}
```

Will line 2 and line 3 will be executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. From the documentation on `wait()`:

1. The current thread must own this object's monitor.
2. The thread releases ownership of this monitor and
3. waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method.
4. The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and
5. resumes execution.

So, point 1 corresponds to the `synchronized()` statement; points 2 3 and 4 are in the `wait()` method, and point 5 corresponds to lines 2 and 3 in your code.

Comment: You mean to say it will immediately relinquish the lock and line 2 and line 3 will be executed when it will reacquire the lock.

Comment: 2nd line is releasing the lock (monitor in JVM speak). 2 & 3 are essentially atomic; this is so that no notifications are lost.

Answer (score 1):

It's what you've just read. Lines 2 and 3 after the `wait` call will only run once the synchronized block of the thread calling `notify` is finished:

> The awakened thread will not be able to proceed until the current thread relinquishes the lock on this object. The awakened thread will compete in the usual manner with any other threads that might be actively competing to synchronize on this object

(This is from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify())

Of course this is because both threads synchronize on the same (`this`) object.